# Required information for UK visa form

Tags: visas, uk

I am from Pakistan. I am planning to apply for a UK tourist visa with my wife and 6-year-old child. I am a businessman and the main applicant. My wife is a housewife. My visit will be for 15 days in London.

I want to ask for some information. I have GBP 4,000 for this visit. Is this enough for 15 days? How do I distribute it in my three visa forms? How to fill these fields on all three forms?

1. What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?
2. The total amount of money you have for this trip?

Please help me with this matter.

Comment: Does £4000 include flights? If not, it should be adequate for 3 people depending on where you plan to stay and what you want to do/see during your trip. It averages out at about £265 per day, but a lot of it could be swallowed up by accommodation costs eg if you plan to stay in a hotel, so may not be as much in practice as it seems in theory.

Comment: *What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?* You are filling the old form. Please use the new form, the questions on that are much easier. That's the first thing I'd suggest. It is located at https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk/product/uk-visit-visa